# Access kubernetes service via server domain

Tags: kubernetes

So I got a running cluster on my server. The server is running `ubuntu 18.06`. **I set up the cluster using `kubeadm`, `kubectl` and `kubelet`.**

**My goal in a nutshell: I want to reach the services with executing `http://myserver.com/service`.**

I am kinda lost with exposing the services to port 8080. The current structure is like this:

> 31001:SERVICE:8080 -> 8080:POD

So I need to redirect the requests incoming using `http://myserver.com/service` to the `kubernetes service` with port 31001.

Current situation: I can only access the cluster via server IP:6443. All pods, services and so forth are up and running.

**So my question: how can I make the services more or less public available on port 8080?**

As requested below:

> Output of `kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o wide`

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
default       pod/articleservice-deployment-6d48989664-jbzs6           1/1     Running   0          5h56m   192.168.0.4     server.address.com           <none>           <none>
default       pod/cartservice-deployment-6b844f45b8-jz45h              1/1     Running   0          5h56m   192.168.0.5     server.address.com           <none>           <none>
default       pod/catalogservice-deployment-d4bd6984c-6qlqg            1/1     Running   0          5h56m   192.168.0.6     server.address.com           <none>           <none>
default       pod/customerservice-deployment-7d6f77fdbb-p42xj          1/1     Running   0          5h56m   192.168.0.7     server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/calico-node-5rl9m                                    2/2     Running   0          5h58m   999.999.99.99   server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-86c58d9df4-h64fg                             1/1     Running   0          6h10m   192.168.0.2     server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/coredns-86c58d9df4-pwfj4                             1/1     Running   0          6h10m   192.168.0.3     server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/etcd-server.address.net                              1/1     Running   0          6h9m    999.999.99.99   server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-apiserver-server.address.net                    1/1     Running   0          6h10m   999.999.99.99   server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-controller-manager-server.address.net           1/1     Running   0          6h9m    999.999.99.99   server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-proxy-xb2qc                                     1/1     Running   0          6h10m   999.999.99.99   server.address.com           <none>           <none>
kube-system   pod/kube-scheduler-server.address.net                    1/1     Running   0          6h9m    999.999.99.99   server.address.com           <none>           <none>

NAMESPACE     NAME                      TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                          AGE     SELECTOR
default       service/articleservice    NodePort    10.97.125.155   <none>        31001:31001/TCP,5005:32001/TCP   5h57m   app=articleservice
default       service/cartservice       NodePort    10.99.42.169    <none>        31002:31002/TCP,5005:32002/TCP   5h57m   app=cartservice
default       service/catalogservice    NodePort    10.106.101.93   <none>        31003:31003/TCP,5005:32003/TCP   5h57m   app=catalogservice
default       service/customerservice   NodePort    10.106.2.159    <none>        31004:31004/TCP,5005:32004/TCP   5h57m   app=customerservice
default       service/kubernetes        ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP                          6h11m   <none>
kube-system   service/calico-typha      ClusterIP   10.96.242.31    <none>        5473/TCP                         5h58m   k8s-app=calico-typha
kube-system   service/kube-dns          ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP                    6h11m   k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR                 AGE     CONTAINERS                IMAGES                                                 SELECTOR
kube-system   daemonset.apps/calico-node   1         1         1       1            1           beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux   5h58m   calico-node,install-cni   quay.io/calico/node:v3.3.2,quay.io/calico/cni:v3.3.2   k8s-app=calico-node
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy    1         1         1       1            1           <none>                        6h11m   kube-proxy                k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy:v1.13.1                          k8s-app=kube-proxy

NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE     CONTAINERS        IMAGES                        SELECTOR
default       deployment.apps/articleservice-deployment    1/1     1            1           5h56m   articleservice    elps/articleservice:1.0.7     app=articleservice
default       deployment.apps/cartservice-deployment       1/1     1            1           5h56m   cartservice       elps/cartservice:1.0.7        app=cartservice
default       deployment.apps/catalogservice-deployment    1/1     1            1           5h56m   catalogservice    elps/catalogservice:1.0.7     app=catalogservice
default       deployment.apps/customerservice-deployment   1/1     1            1           5h56m   customerservice   elps/customerservice:1.0.7    app=customerservice
kube-system   deployment.apps/calico-typha                 0/0     0            0           5h58m   calico-typha      quay.io/calico/typha:v3.3.2   k8s-app=calico-typha
kube-system   deployment.apps/coredns                      2/2     2            2           6h11m   coredns           k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.6      k8s-app=kube-dns

NAMESPACE     NAME                                                    DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE     CONTAINERS        IMAGES                        SELECTOR
default       replicaset.apps/articleservice-deployment-6d48989664    1         1         1       5h56m   articleservice    elps/articleservice:1.0.7     app=articleservice,pod-template-hash=6d48989664
default       replicaset.apps/cartservice-deployment-6b844f45b8       1         1         1       5h56m   cartservice       elps/cartservice:1.0.7        app=cartservice,pod-template-hash=6b844f45b8
default       replicaset.apps/catalogservice-deployment-d4bd6984c     1         1         1       5h56m   catalogservice    elps/catalogservice:1.0.7     app=catalogservice,pod-template-hash=d4bd6984c
default       replicaset.apps/customerservice-deployment-7d6f77fdbb   1         1         1       5h56m   customerservice   elps/customerservice:1.0.7    app=customerservice,pod-template-hash=7d6f77fdbb
kube-system   replicaset.apps/calico-typha-5fc4874c76                 0         0         0       5h58m   calico-typha      quay.io/calico/typha:v3.3.2   k8s-app=calico-typha,pod-template-hash=5fc4874c76
kube-system   replicaset.apps/coredns-86c58d9df4                      2         2         2       6h10m   coredns           k8s.gcr.io/coredns:1.2.6      k8s-app=kube-dns,pod-template-hash=86c58d9df4
```

Comment: show output of all your objects: kubectl get all --all-namespaces -o wide

Comment: Added, thanks for your input :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Ingress` is that you need. This is how it works:

```
   internet
        |
   [ Ingress ]
   --|-----|--
   [ Services ]
```

Let's say you have any k8s Deployment with the label: `app: deployment-01` with `containerPort: 8888`

So, you need to create:

1. Service (say service-01)
2. Ingress (say ingress-01)

If you want to reach service-01 by link http://myserver.com/service then your Service YAML should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-01
spec:
  selector:
    app: deployment-01
  ports:
  - name: web
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8888
```

and Ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-01
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myserver.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /service
        backend:
          serviceName: service-01
          servicePort: 8080
```

that's it!

> Note: This assumes that you have already deployed the Ingress
>   controller and it is working.

Comment: @elp glad to help you, reading this also might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Done :) Even tho I have not done this part: `Note: This assumes that you have already deployed the Ingress controller and it is working.`. It is just about the seperate deployment script which starts a pod with a nginx ingress controller for instance, right? :)

Comment: Yes, you're right. When we talk about Ingress there might be two meanings: resource (as I've already shown) and controller. Controller usually is a Deployment (or DeamonSet) of the different Ingress controller types, like: nginx-ingress (Ingress controller by Kubernetes team), nginxnic (Ingress controller by Nginx team), traefik etc. So, defining Ingress resourse, in fact, is an instruction for generating Nginx configuration to the Ingress controller. Once your controller will be deployed you'll be able to see it within the controller's pod